# Gulp run tasks in loop

Tags: javascript, gulp

So I have some trouble with a gulp script.
I need to do some operations in a loop. If it triggers the tasks by themselves they do what they should.
Problem is if I trigger "qs" only the "copy" tasks works but then the "pack" task somehow does not do what it should, but it gets triggered.

I condensed the task to make everything a bit smaller. But what should be done is copy a folder to a dir, then unzip something to the same dir. All of that three times (flags).
After that's been done the "pack" task should zip those three dirs into three zips.

```
gulp.task('qs', ['qs:copy', 'qs:pack'], function() { });

var flags = ['a','b','c'];

gulp.task('qs:copy',  function() {
  return flags.map(function(flag) {
     return gulp.src(['_tmp/**/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'+flag+'/'));

     return gulp.src(['packages/test-'+flag+'*.zip'])
        .pipe(decompress())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'+flag+'/tmp/'));
  });
});


gulp.task('qs:pack', ['qs:copy'] , function() {
  return flags.map(function(flag) {
    gulp.src(['/build/'+flag+'/**/*'])
    .pipe(zip('qs-'+flag+'.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/build/'));
  });
});
```

Comment: In flags.map are 2 return statements. The second will never get called.

Comment: not true. gulp calls them parallel. i think merging the streams could possibly work.